# Можно ли грузить строки в string.xml с сервера android?

Tags: android, строки

У себя в приложении я использую строки которые хранятся в специально созданном файле - `string.xml`. В этом файле по-логике должны быть все строки из приложения. У меня на сегодня внедрено три языка для каждого из которых есть отдельный файлик со строками. Это вроде как нормальная практика при работе с несколькими языками. 
Всего в приложении будет 11 языков, и соответственно нужно будет делать перевод.

И вот возник вопрос у моего заказчика, можно ли как-то использовать транслейтер-тул на сервере для перевода строк. Если я правильно понял, нужно будет каждую строку и слово грузить с сервера, что не сможет не сказаться на скорости работы приложения. Во вторых мне не очень понятно как именно это вообще будет происходить, если это все-таки реально. Но мне почему-то кажется что такое либо невозможно, либо таким лучше не заниматься, потому-что очень многое может пойти не так. И в третьих, может лучше сразу сказать что это нереально, и не запариваться, потому-что мне кажется что это вообще бред если честно, зачем заморачиваться, если есть нормальный проверенный способ, который работает везде и всегда. Ведь если не будет сети например, то пользователь просто не сможет получить нужные ему строки и увидеть их на экране.

Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с такой задачей и знает как решить этот вопрос. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Любые ресурсы в андроид приложение на этапе выполнения изменять нельзя.

Comment: это я так понял ответ на мой вопрос?))) получается я все-таки правильно думал?

Comment: Да, вы правы.  Лучше всего решать это через разные файлы string.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ресурсы приложения компилируются утилитой *AAPT* и встраиваются в готовый код, так что изменить их в рантайме невозможно - это лобовой ответ.

Более хитро, конечно можно попытаться переопределить метод `Context.getString()`, который отвечает за извлечение ресурсов - в конечном итоге к нему стягиваются все вызовы. Но беда в том, что метод помечен как `final`, так что переопределить его не получится.

Можно конечно перекорежить весь код своего приложения и попробовать извлекать строчные ресурсы своим методом `getMyString()`, чтобы он стучался в сеть ну и т.д., но даже это не поможет, потому что строки загружаются самой осью напрямую при загрузке `layout/menu` где-то в кишках системы.

Проще наверное объяснить заказчику, что онлайн транслятор только ухудшит приложение. Качество перевода благотворно сказывается на количестве закачек - это вам любой девелопер скажет. Я лично всегда заказываю перевод у носителей языка и даже не заморачиваюсь услугами сельских учителей испанского/французского/немецкого и далее по списку.

Comment: спасибо большое, потому-что я честно говоря не был уверен в своем мнении по этому поводу, и поэтому решил спросить здесь чтобы удостоверится. Спасибо еще раз!!